# Regex replacement of string literals in Java

Tags: java, regex

I'm trying to keep a list of Java identifiers. I've managed to remove all seperators, operators, and keywords, but there are string literals still causing problems. What would be a regular expression to remove any string literals with the `someString.replaceAll(expression here ," ")`?

Answer (score 0):

String replacedSomeString =     someString.replaceAll("[a-zA-Z]" ," ");

use this to replace all the letters.

Comment: I sure hope you don't think this statement changes `someString`.  It doesn't.